# enviar e-mail HTML com MAPI

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Bom dia.

Alguém já enviou algum e-mail onde no corpo do texto é enviado um código HTML.

No meu caso estou precisando salvar uma tabela no corpo do texto.

Utilizando o Outlook funciona, porém se utilizar o live mail, é mostrado para mim no corpo do texto o código html.

Se colocar o arquivo html em anexo funciona, porém se colocar mais de um anexo ai não é apresentado nada no texto.

Desde já obrigado.

Comment: Está utilizando Delphi para fazer o envio? Pode postar o código. Ou seria mais a nível de programas de envio de e-mail?

Comment: Estou utilizando o delphi 7 e a api do windows Mapi.

Comment: pode postar o código que está utilizando para analisarmos ? E sugerir uma alteração?